# SharePoint 2013 User Profile Service - Attributes Not Being Imported

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, sharepoint-server

My SP 2013 User Profile Service is configured to import all active users within 2 domains; external.company.com (external domain) and company.org (internal domain). The UPS is setup on the external domain, external.company.com while AD is on company.org. One of the attributes (Company) selected to import for users on both domains appears to be sporadic.  It imports for some users, but not others even though this attribute is part of that person's AD profile.  The user profile imports without any errors.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: I have seen this same thing with Company.  I haven't come up with a solution yet either though.

Comment: I have a similar issue in that one of my 2 custom attributes are not being displayed in mysite both are mapped to terms and both are populated in AD. As for your issue, I am keep seeing mention of increasing the timeout for FIM but normally this when you can't populate the container on a new sync connection . I maybe clutching at straws.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?